# How do you send a web push notification over FCM from server with actions?

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, firebase-notifications, web-push

I am successfully sending web push notifications over FCM from the server using Firebase.  One thing I am missing though is sending events along with this.

When I click on the notification it does nothing (not even take me to the site). How do I enable something like that?

Currently I am passing a JSON object like

```
{
    "to": "[add your token]",
    "notification": {
        "title": "Working Good",
        "body": "[add your message]"
    },
    "priority": "high"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In service worker, listen to global [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/push) event to handle your notification manually.
Then call [`showNotification()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration/showNotification) method to display the notification.
In options object you can specify a list of action buttons your notification would have.

```js
self.addEventListener("push", event => {

    const {title, body} = JSON.parse(event.data.text());
    event.waitUntil(self.registration.showNotification(title, {
        body,
        actions: [{
            action: "delete",
            title: "Delete"
        }, {
            action: "markAsRead",
            title: "Mark as read"
        }],
    }));

});
```

Listen to [`notificationclick`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/notificationclick) event to handle clicks on your action buttons or notification itself:

```js
self.addEventListener("notificationclick", event => {

    // Hide the notification
    event.notification.close();

    switch (event.notification.data.action) {

        // If an action button has been clicked
        case "delete":
        case "markAsRead":
            // Send some request to your server
            break;

        // User haven't clicked any action buttons, only the notification itself
        default:
            // Opening a tab
            clients.openWindow("/");

    }

});
```